# I have a question about an issue where checkboxes are automatically checked when dropping a file into a drag and drop zone

Tags: reactjs

When selecting files and dropping them into the drag-and-drop zone

I implemented it so that the file row list is output.

There is a problem.

The check box is automatically checked.

In developer tools, the confirmChecked function is called as many as the number of file rows.

Could this be related?

Why is the onChecked function automatically executed when drag and drop?

If anyone knows the cause of this problem or how to fix it, please let me know.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import '../styles/FileAttach2.scss';


function FileAttach2(props) {
  // state

  // 체크된 항목
  const [indexesArrayForChekedList, setIndexesArrayForChekedList] = useState([]);
  const [filesToUpload, setFilesToUpload] = useState([]);

  // 1122
  const moveRowUp = params => {
  };
  const moveRowDown = params => {
  };

  // checkbox 관련
  const confirmChecked = useCallback(
    index => {
      if (indexesArrayForChekedList.includes(index)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    [indexesArrayForChekedList],
  );

  const handleCheckedStatus = useCallback(
    (e, idx) => {
      const checked = e.target.checked;

      if (checked) {
        const indexArrayForUpdate = indexesArrayForChekedList.filter(el => {
          return el != idx;
        });
        setIndexesArrayForChekedList(indexArrayForUpdate);
      } else {
        setIndexesArrayForChekedList(prev => [...prev, idx]);
      }
    },
    [indexesArrayForChekedList],
  );

  const deleteRowByIndex = useCallback(
    idx => {
      const afterDeleteRow = filesToUpload.filter(file => {
        return file.index != idx;
      });
      setFilesToUpload(afterDeleteRow);
    },
    [filesToUpload],
  );

  // dropzone 관련
  const onDrop = acceptedFiles => {
    const filesData = acceptedFiles.map((file, index) => {
      return { index: filesToUpload.length + index, name: file.name, size: file.size };
    });
    setFilesToUpload(prev => [...prev, ...filesData]);
  };

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, open, acceptedFiles } = useDropzone({
    noClick: true,
    noKeyboard: true,
    onDrop,
  });

  // FileRow template
  const files = filesToUpload.map(file => (
    <div className="fileRow" key={file.index}>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkBox"
          onChange={e => handleCheckedStatus(e, file.index)}
          checked={confirmChecked(file.index)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>{file.name}</div>
      <div>{file.size} (bytes)</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteRowByIndex(file.index)}>
        삭제
      </button>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="">
      <button type="button" onClick={open}>
        Open File Dialog
      </button>
      <div {...getRootProps({ className: 'dropzone' })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {filesToUpload.length !== 0 ? (
          <div>
            <div className="fileRowHeader">
              <button onClick={moveRowDown}>아래로</button>
              <button onClick={moveRowUp}>위로</button>
            </div>
            <div>{files}</div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ''
        )}
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FileAttach2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `true` when `indexesArrayForChekedList` includes your index which will always be `true` at the beginning.

Try below code in your `confirmChecked` function

```
const confirmChecked = useCallback(
    index => indexesArrayForChekedList.includes(index),
    [indexesArrayForChekedList],
);
```